# module import in loop python, value not updating

Tags: python, loops, import, module, iteration

I have a file that contains:

```
<html>
    <h1>Hello There</h1>
    <p>
    This is an example of a pml file
    </p>
    <pml>
    def f():
        return "<h2>First PML block</h2>"
    pml = f()
    </pml>
    <p>Here is another paragraph</p>
    <pml>
    def g():
        return "<h2>Second PML block</h2>"
    pml = g()
    </pml>
    <p>This is the last paragraph.</p>
    <pml>
    def h():
        return "<h2>Third PML block</h2>"
    pml = h()
    </pml>
</html>
```

I'm writing a python script that will produce an output file that replaces the pml blocks with the result of the code in the block.  I want the output file to look like:

```
<html>
<h1>Hello There</h1>
<p>
This is an example of a pml file
</p>
<h2>First PML block</h2>
<p>Here is another paragraph</p>
<h2>Second PML block</h2>
<p>This is the last paragraph.</p>
<h2>Third PML block</h2>
</html>
```

Here is my script:

```
import sys

#define main

def main(argv):
    #make sure usage is proper
    if len(sys.argv) != 3:
        print 'Usage: pmlparser.py <input_file> <output_file>'
    else:
          #get the filenames
          inputfilename = sys.argv[1]
          outputfilename = sys.argv[2]
          #open the files
          with open(inputfilename,"r") as inputfile, open(outputfilename,"w") as outputfile:    
                  for line in inputfile:
                         if not "<pml>" in line:
                               outputfile.write(line)
                         else:
                               pmlfile = open("pmlcode.py","a")
                               for line in inputfile:
                                       if not "</pml>" in line:
                                              pmlfile.write(line[1:])
                                       else:
                                              #I think the problem is somewhere in here
                                              pmlfile.close()
                                              import pmlcode
                                              outputfile.write(pmlcode.pml + "\n")
                                              break         

if __name__ == "__main__":
   main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Unfortunately, I get the following as my result:

```
<html>
<h1>Hello There</h1>
<p>
This is an example of a pml file
</p>
<h2>First PML block</h2>
<p>Here is another paragraph</p>
<h2>First PML block</h2>
<p>This is the last paragraph.</p>
<h2>First PML block</h2>
</html>
```

I am iteratively importing pmlcode.py, and trying to write the new value for pml to the outputfile.  However, this script keeps writing the original value for pml to the output file.

I've tried the following as a test:

a.py:

```
def f():
    return 1
var = f()
def g():
    return 2
var = g()
```

b.py:

```
import a
print a.var
```

$> python b.py

2

I just started learning Python yesterday, so I apologize if my question sounds dumb or if I'm misunderstanding something.  I appreciate any help!

Comment: Not a bad code for someone who started to learn Python yesterday :)

Comment: Importing a module a second time doesn't do anything.  What is the nature of your `pmlcode` file?

Comment: Stephan: I've already given expected output.

Comment: do you have to do pml = f(), pml = g(), pml = h() every time? or do you care that the variable be named differently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`import` is not the tool you want here. As you discovered, once you've imported a module, you always get the same module; Python caches it in memory for performance. The problem, in other words, is *not* that `pmlcode.py` isn't getting updated, but rather that it is only actually read the first time `import pmlcode` is executed.

Since you already have a string, why write it to a file and then import it? Just use `exec` directly on the string.

Comment: Additionally, you can pass an explicit `globals` dictionary to the `exec` statement and read the value of `pml` out of the dict after the `exec`.

Comment: kindall,
Thanks for the response. I'll give the exec thing a try! Like I said, I just started using Python for the first time yesterday.  I haven't really seen the exec method/function/keyword/whateverit'scalled until now.

Comment: Just had to say: you can use imp.reload to get changes made to an already imported module.

Comment: Yes you can reload modules... still, writing a string to the file and then importing the file is the long way 'round.

Comment: If I import imp and pmlcode at the very top of my script, and replace the previous line that said "import pmlcode" with imp.reload(pmlcode), I still get the same incorrect output....:(

Comment: Part of the issue here is that the requirements of the project state that variables/functions in one pml block must be available for reuse in subsequent pml blocks.  Will exec() be able to use variables/functions that were referenced in a previous loop iteration?

Comment: Sure, if you use the same dictionary for globals each time.

Comment: So I can build a string up over the loop iterations that contains all of the code in the pml blocks, and then call exec on that string....

Comment: I got it to work by building the pml string up, calling exec on it, and writing the pml variable to the outputfile.
Thanks very much for all the help!
I would like to learn the globals() dictionary method, but I can't seem to understand the usage of exec() and globals() from the Python docs.